# How can I calculate my damage with Bleed in Remnant 2?

Tags: remnant-2

I watched a super high damage bow video (without bleed)

In this build it's easy to test the DPS on the dummies in Ward 13.

I have an idea for a build, but I can't test it because dummies in Ward 13 don't bleed.

I wanted to know how I can calculate the damage from my build.

The idea is:

- Twisted Wounds: +20% dmg (bleeding)
- Ravager's mark: +20% / +30% dmg (bleeding)
- Stone of Expanse: +12% dmg
- Zania's Malice: +10% / +20% / +30% dmg
- Ring of Flawed Beauty: +25% dmg
- Mythic Ranged Damage: +10% dmg
- Solid Weakspot Damage: +3.814% dmg
- S.H.A.R.K. - 7% / 14% / 21% / 28% / 35%

Total damage modifier: 107.814% ~ 165.814%

Bow Sagittarius +10: 294 dmg (+115% dmg) (total 222.814% ~ 280.814% ?)

But what's the "base damage" or what's the formula to calculate what's the damage I'd be dealing to dummies if they bled?

---

Here's what I've tried:

## WARNING: this is probably wrong in the final formulas

I've been playing around, and I think I figured out some of the basics.

Base damage = Weapon Damage

Class: Hunter / Invader

1. Base scenario: no equips, Sagittarius +10 (294 damage)

Hit against dummy (non weakspot) = 412 damage

`base damage * (1 + damage modifiers + ranged damage modifiers)`

`294 * (1 + 0 + 0.4(hunter)) = 411.6`

2. Ring with 7% extra damage

Hit against dummy (non weakspot) = 432

`294 * (1 + 0.07 + 0.4) = 432.18`

3. No rings, Testing weakspot

Hit against dummy (weakspot) = 947

The previous formula makes sense, but now we augment the formula with Weakspot damage

`base damage * (1 + damage modifiers + ranged damage modifiers) * (1 + weakspot modifiers)`

`294 * (1 + 0.4) * (1 + 0.15(hunter) + 1.15) = 946.68`

4. weakspot damage +25% ring

Hit against dummy (weakspot) = 1050

`294 * (1 + 0.4) * (1 + 0.15 + 1.15 + 0.25) = 1049.58`

5. testing crit, no items, non weakspot

Hit against dummy (non weakspot, crit) = 617

`base damage * (1 + damage modifiers + ranged damage modifiers) * (1 + weakspot modifiers) * (1 + crit damage)`

`294 * (1 + 0.4) * (1 + 0) * (1 + 0.5) = 617.4`

---

## Warning, this is probably wrong

From the tested scenarios above, I'd assume there are 3 multiplicative damages (base, crit, weakspot).

So, the max damage with that set would be something like:

`294 * (1 + 0.5(H.Shroud) + 0.4 + 0.2(Twisted) + 0.3(Ravager) + 0.06(S.Expanse) + 0.1(relic) + 0.35(Shark)) * (1 + 0.15 + 1.15(bow) + 0.3(Zania) + 0.25(FlawedB) + 0.03814(relic)) * (1 + 0.5(crit)) = 3706.3789434`

Without Hunter Shroud `3069.5440734`
Without H.S. and Crit `2046.3627156`
Without bleed and above `1621.8061356`

I'm sure there's something wrong with the formula, maybe Bleeding damage applies differently or there's something else wrong here.

I'm sure I have already dealt like ~7k damage before in a single shot.

**Update**: it seems that a fully charged bow shot has a MULTIPLICATIVE 70% damage, `3706.3789434 * 1.7 = 6300.84420378`, this would explain numbers I'm seeing, but I don't know if the formula is exactly correct, but the numbers make sense.